# How to give font-awesomes icon a fixed width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using `Bootstrap` and `Font Awesome` to make a table like the one from [FAQ zalando](http://www.zalando.de/faq/).

So on the left side, there should be an icon, and on the right side, there should be text.

I want the text to be exactly under each other, they should not be out of alignment with each other. If I give the icons a span, then it will be ignored.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <i class="span2 icon-user "></i>
    <div value='register' class="span4">
        Registrierung
    </div>
    <i class="icon-mobile-phone span2"></i>
    <div id='Newsletter' class="span4">
        Newsletter
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <i class="icon-euro span2"></i>
    <div value='kost' class="span4">
        Kosten
    </div>

    <i class="icon-phone span2"></i>
    <div id='probleme' class="span4">
        Probleme
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add left padding to your container div and put the icon as a background image on that instead of using a seperate i tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your icon inside the element and make it behave as an `inline-block` so you can change its `width` and `margin`.

http://jsfiddle.net/LeBen/B9yjd/

Answer (score 40):

As an update to this, FontAwesome now has [fixed-width](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#fixed-width) support built in.

```
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>
```

The `fa-fw` class supplies the fixed-width style.

Answer (score 2):

Both, the original code of the Zalando website and the Fiddle by LeBen, are not "ideal" - espacially when it comes to HTML semantics.

Why having empty elements if you only want a background image for an element?

Just add the icon as background-image and set the padding-left for all these elements to the required value.

Comment: 100% this. What's wrong with `<div value='register' class="icon-user span4">`?

Answer (score 0):

Just target the icons classes directly adding your styles in css:

```
[class*="btn-"]:before,
[class^=" btn"]:before {
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

And there's no need for an empty , just use:

```
<div class="row">
  <div value='register' class="icon-user span4">
    Registrierung
  </div>
  <div id='Newsletter' class="icon-mobile-phone span4">
    Newsletter
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just had this issue playing around with the options after not wanting to bang all my FontAwesome icons in spans/divs.  Adding class 'fa-fw' did indeed solve it, but so does simply adjusting the width of the icon with CSS (maybe a new thing as this is an old post), so no extra classes needed if you have many icons.  'svg-inline--fa' was a common class for all my icons - see example

```css
.item{
  padding: 5px;
}
    
.svg-inline--fa{
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 40px !important;
}
```

```html
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js" defer></script>
                
                <div class="item">
                    <i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>
                    Fast, local and friendly team
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <i class="fas fa-tags"></i>
                    Honest and transparent pricing
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                        <i class="fas fa-handshake"></i>
                    All our work is guaranteed
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-check"></i>
                    Trained to the highest UK standards
                </div>
```